# react-error-overlay with webpack-dev-middleware and webpack-hot-middleware not work

Tags: reactjs

use `react-error-overlay` with `webpack-dev-middleware` and `webpack-hot-middleware`, I want get error like this

[image]

### but, I got this

[image]

how to beautify react error overlay?